# Yet another proposal meant to suck your eyeballs away from this site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I've asked 2 or 3 people in the last few weeks who have had their "Bible questions" smashed by the Truth Hammer to go start up their own site.  [One did](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110218/bible-answers), but I think it missed the mark a bit.

I proposed last year (or maybe two year ago) a Catholic Culture site, but that was a bit too constrained, so now I think I'd like to propose (in the middle of the night) a [Christian Living](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110376/christian-living) site.  Truth questions, Personal Interpretation of the Bible, Catholicism, Protestantism, Dogs Cats, living together.

Just a wonderful vision of the future, I think you'll all agree.

And before you give me the perfunctory -1 with or without the song and dance, please remember that there is an audience for this and you may not be it.

Comment: Every single sample question you made would be closed as opinion based on every site in the network! There are lots of good Christian living questions, but not like those.

Comment: Peter, those questions really are hard to take seriously. Conceptually, as I said, I agree with you. However, I'm not looking for a free-for-all debacle that questions like those would most certainly foster. The trouble I have with Christianity SE is finding consistency in the execution of the sites parameters. I see one question that gets closed for inciting opinion, though it has real value. I see other questions which should obviously be moderated for the exact same reason, though they loiter on the site with impunity.

Comment: While they make great subjects for discussion, they really aren't good questions for determining an accepted answer.  With my old account on here, I've been around about as long as you have.  It has taken a LONG time to come to terms with this being the better approach.  People want answers to their faith questions.  *We* just don't have the authority to answer - we can only express opinions.

Answer (score 4):

There may be an audience for this; the question is whether or not there is a host for it. Questions like

- What Catholic traditions are there at Easter that families can celebrate outside the liturgy?
- How can I help my children keep the Christian faith when they have to go to public school?
- What should I do in church if a man next to me is wearing a hat?

have absolutely no *single correct verifiable* answer that I can see. (The main Help page for SE sites does say to avoid things that are likely to generate discussion, or that are opinion-based.) They wouldn't fit well on a Stack Exchange site in general.

You may be able to create a site for this; but it shouldn't be a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Matt, I remember when you fist started posting here.  I still look forward to your great answers.

Comment: My feeling is that a reasonable, well argued, answer is a good answer and there are many other stackexchange sites that back that up (world building, parenting, the workplace).  Christian Living is a section in book stores and the dewey decimal system that stands apart from Christian Theology.  I think you followed the site when I created that "Catholic Culture" proposal (which apparently went under the radar).  This would have been the same, but broader.  I still am gonna try and get the site built, mainly because that employee who thinks he owns the place on Area51 is a good motivator.

Comment: @PeterTurner The three sites you mention are my least favorite of all the SE sites, or at least the least SEish. There's a difference between a good answer and a right answer; and I think SE is more oriented towards the latter.

Comment: @PeterTurner to the extent that they work, it's because they've embraced [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) principles. I suggest you import the lessons there into your Christian Living proposal.

Comment: It's similar to parents.se